# How to use %ROWTYPE inside package body

Tags: plsql

I am trying to use `%rowtype` inside a package

```
create or replace PACKAGE p IS

procedure TYPE_INSERT_DUMMY(ins acr_projected_new%ROWTYPE);

END p;

create or replace PACKAGE BODY p IS

PROCEDURE TYPE_INSERT_DUMMY (ins acr_projected_new%ROWTYPE) 
IS
BEGIN
insert into ins(WEEKEND_DATE,USERID,TIMESTAMP,ACR_PROJECTED,ARTIFICIAL_ID)
values(sysdate,'NN57875',sysdate,1,1);
end TYPE_INSERT_DUMMY;

end p;
```

When I try the code above, I get error:

> Error(6,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>
> Error(6,13): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: Could be a **synonym** or **grant** problem

Comment: Ist the package in the same schema (=same owner) as the table? If not you have to add the owner to the table name.

Comment: YES both package are in same schema as the table

Comment: you don't insert into `ins`. you should be inserting into `acr_projected_new`

Comment: My requirement is to insert data into 'Type ins is table of  acr_projected_new%ROWTYPE

Comment: `ins` is a PL/SQL record structure, i.e. a variable with multiple attributes, not a database table you can insert into. Did you want to populate it with values maybe? That would be a `select into`, not an `insert`. (Although as it's currently an `in` parameter it's not writeable.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert data into a Table Type variable, you cannot use `insert into` syntax.

In Package spec, you define the **TYPE**
In Package Body's Procedure, you create a new object of that **TYPE** and then use `extend` for inserting values

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE p
IS
    Type ins is table of acr_projected_new%ROWTYPE
    PROCEDURE TYPE_INSERT_DUMMY;
END p;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY p
IS
    PROCEDURE TYPE_INSERT_DUMMY()
    IS
        insvariable ins := ins();
    BEGIN
        insvariable.extend(1);
        insvariable(insvariable.LAST) := ins(sysdate,'NN57875',sysdate,1,1);
    END TYPE_INSERT_DUMMY;
END p;
```

Comment: My requirement is to insert data into 'Type ins is table of  acr_projected_new%ROWTYPE

Comment: I tried the above code it gives me error :
Error(8,42): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INS'

Comment: Error(8,42): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INS'

Comment: It means that you need to pass more values. You are inserting values in a record type variable which is of type `acr_projected_new` you will need to insert all the fields

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below and it is working for me:

```
create or replace PACKAGE p 

IS   

procedure TYPE_INSERT_DUMMY;

END p;



create or replace PACKAGE BODY p IS

PROCEDURE TYPE_INSERT_DUMMY

IS
Type acr is table of acr_projected_new%ROWTYPE;
ins acr;


    BEGIN

    select sysdate, 'NN57875', sysdate, 1, 1 
    bulk collect into ins
    from dual;


    END TYPE_INSERT_DUMMY;

end p;
```